# Powershell: Getting Variables from Parallel Jobs

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that does a double dns lookup. First it passes the IP to the server to return a Hostname, then takes the hostname and sends it back through to return an IP address. This is used to make sure that DNS is registering the correct IP with the correct Hostname.

My boss wants something a bit more complicated. While I have the output pushed to an HTML document, I've had to make it so that it calls all of our scopes at once and then displays a summary page. The summary page has a link to each subnet's results page and is supposed to show at a glance the valid responses, the invalid responses, the ones with no hostname and the total.

I cannot seem to get the variable $($valid) to display on the table correctly, as it keeps giving me a 0. the same with the others. The code I have is listed below:

```
#BEGIN
<#
.NOTES 
    ScriptName : iphostip.ps1 
    Created By : W. Alex Williams
    Contact    : 
    Date Coded : 5/15/2013 10:29pm 
.PURPOSE
    This script is used to check DNS records to make sure that the Hostname is registered to the same IP as what it shows in DNS.

#> 
#Gather the list of IPs...
$listofIPs = Get-Content .\IPList.txt

#Set the HTML Header
$header = @'
<style>
BODY{font-family:Verdana; background-color:black;background-image:url("../assets/bg.jpg");;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-attachment:fixed;}
TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;width:75%;}
TH{font-size:1.3em; border-width: 1px;padding: 2px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:#8FD8D8}
TD{border-width: 1px;padding: 2px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:white}
H1{color:white; text-align:center;}
H3{color:white; text-align:center;}
</style>
<title> DNS Integrity Report</title>
<link rel=”icon” href=”assets/favicon.ico” type=”image/x-icon”>
<link rel=”shortcut icon” href=”assets/favicon.ico” type=”image/x-icon”>
'@
#Setting some misc variables....
$linktofile = "<h1>Results</h1>"
$Valid = "0"
$Invalid = "0"
$NoHostName = "0"
$scriptPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
$Timestamp = Get-Date -format yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss
$LogDirectory = $scriptPath + "\logs\" + $Timestamp
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $LogDirectory | out-null

#Looping the function through the list:

$JobWork = {
param ($ipnet, $scriptPath, $header, $Timestamp, $LogDirectory)


$ResultList = @()
$ResultList += "<h1>DNS Integrity Report</h1>"
$ResultList += "<table align='center'><tbody><tr><th>Original IP</th><th>IsAlive</th><th>Hostname</th><th>Checked IP</th><th>Match?</th></tr>"



$i = 0
while ($i -lt 254) 
    {

    $i++
    $ip = $ipnet + $i

    $result = $null
    Write "Checking $($IP)..."
    $currentEAP = $ErrorActionPreference
    #Don't wanna wake the neighbors
    $ErrorActionPreference = "silentlycontinue"
    #Getting the Hostname
    $result = [System.Net.Dns]::gethostentry($ip)
    $ErrorActionPreference = $currentEAP
    $IsAlive = Test-Connection $ip -quiet -count 1
    If ($Result)
        {
        $IPCheck = "Unknown"
        #Getting the IP from the Hostname
        $IPCheck = @(([net.dns]::GetHostEntry($Result.Hostname)).AddressList)
        If ($IP -eq $IPCheck)
            {
                $TrueFalse = "<td style='background-color:green;'>True</td>"
                $Valid++
            }
        Else
            {
                #Something must be fishy....
                $TrueFalse = "<td style='background-color:red;'>False</td>"
                $Invalid++
            }
        $Resultlist += "<tr><td>$($IP)</td><td>$($IsAlive)</td><td>$([string]$Result.Hostname)</td><td>$($IPCheck)</td>$($TrueFalse)<tr>"
        }
    Else
        {
            #Well duh. If there was no hostname, of course it couldn't check for an IP
            $Resultlist += "<tr><td>$IP</td><td>$($IsAlive)</td><td>No Hostname Found</td><td>None</td><td style='background-color:Orange;'>N/A</td><tr>"
            $NoHostName++
        }
    }
$OutputName = "$($LogDirectory)\$($ipnet)0.htm"
$Count = $Valid + $Invalid + $NoHostName
$Resultlist += "</tbody></table><br /><p style='text-align:center;color:red;background-color:black;padding:3px;'><tr><td>Valid: $($Valid)  ||  </td><td>Invalid: $($Invalid)  ||  </td><td>No Host Name: $($NoHostName)  ||  </td><td>Total: $($Count)</td><tr>"
$resultlist += "<br /><p style='text-align:center;color:red;background-color:black;padding:3px;'>Results from IpHostIp.ps1 Script created by Salerno Systems Administration team. This program is free to use, but please do not claim ownership.</p>"
#Sending in the results:
ConvertTo-HTML -head $header -body $resultlist | Out-File $OutputName
}   
$linktofile += "<table align='center'><tbody><tr><th>Link to file</th><th>Valid</th><th>Invalid</th><th>No Hostname</th></tr>"
foreach ($ipnet in $listofIPs)
{
Start-Job -ScriptBlock $jobWork -ArgumentList $ipnet, $scriptPath, $header, $Timestamp, $LogDirectory
$linktofile += "<tr><td><a href='file:///$($LogDirectory)\$($ipnet)0.htm'>$($ipnet)0</a></td><td>$($Valid)</td><td>$($Invalid)</td><td>$($NoHostName)</td></tr>"
}

Get-Job | Wait-Job
Get-Job | Receive-Job
Get-Job | Remove-Job
$indexhead = @'
<style>
BODY{font-family:Verdana; background-color:black;background-image:url("../assets/bg.jpg");;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-attachment:fixed;}
TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;width:75%;}
TH{font-size:1.3em; border-width: 1px;padding: 2px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:#8FD8D8}
TD{border-width: 1px;padding: 2px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:white}
H1{color:white; text-align:center;}
H3{color:white; text-align:center;}
</style>
<title> DNS Integrity Report</title>
<link rel=”icon” href=”assets/favicon.ico” type=”image/x-icon”>
<link rel=”shortcut icon” href=”assets/favicon.ico” type=”image/x-icon”>
'@
$linktofile += "</tbody></table>"
ConvertTo-HTML -head $indexhead -body $linktofile | Out-File "$($Timestamp).index.htm"
echo "Done."
#END
```

The IPList.txt file must be created and to set it up just enter the first 3 octets of the IP range (IE 192.168.1.)

Any help is greatly appreciated.